# How to filter a list of items for the first match in a AutoCompleteBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, autocompletebox

My goal is to allow the user to hit the tab key and the autocompletebox to immediately select the first item in the dropdown list. Problem is I can't seem to figure out how to access the first filtered item. Any ideas?

At first I thought the property IsTextCompletionEnabled = true would solve my problem. But if I use FilterMode = Contains, the textcompletion feature doesn't help because nothing is completed.

The ItemsSource doesn't actually change. I need to get to the first item in the filtered list not the itemssource. Is there a way?

Here is my code:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Recording> MyMusic = new List<Recording>();

            MyMusic.Add(new Recording("Chris Sells", "Chris Sells Live", new DateTime(2008, 3, 5)));
            MyMusic.Add(new Recording("Chris Sells", "CSells Tells", new DateTime(2004, 4, 6)));
            MyMusic.Add(new Recording("Luka Abrus", "The Road to Redmond", new DateTime(2007, 8, 3)));
            MyMusic.Add(new Recording("Luka Abrus", "CLuka", new DateTime(2005, 12, 8)));
            MyMusic.Add(new Recording("Luka Abrus", "CLove and Luka", new DateTime(2005, 12, 8)));
            MyMusic.Add(new Recording("Jim Hance", "The Best of Jim Hance", new DateTime(2007, 2, 6)));

            Records.ItemsSource = MyMusic;
        }

        private void Records_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
                Records.SelectedItem = ((IEnumerable<object>)Records.ItemsSource).First();
        }
    }

    public class Recording
    {
        public Recording() { }
        public Recording(string artistName, string cdName, DateTime release)
        {
            Artist = artistName;
            Name = cdName;
            ReleaseDate = release;
        }
        public string Artist { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the xaml:

```
<Controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="Records" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="182"
                          ValueMemberPath="Name" KeyDown="Records_KeyDown"
                           FilterMode="Contains"
                          IsTextCompletionEnabled="True">
    <Controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</Controls:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to pass a predicate to the `First` method,

```
    private void Records_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            Records.SelectedItem = 
                 Records.ItemsSource
                     .First(item => 
                         item.Name.Contains(textBoxValue) || 
                         item.Artist.Contains(textBoxValue));
        }
    }
```

This way the selected item will be the first to match the predicate, or in this case, the first where the item name or artist contains the current value in the textbox.

Comment: Awesome worked like a charm. To get it to work I had to make it more specific to my situation but this works great. Here is what I did:             if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
            {
                Records.SelectedItem =
            ((IEnumerable<Recording>)Records.ItemsSource)
            .First(item =>
             item.Name.Contains(Records.Text) ||
             item.Artist.Contains(Records.Text));

Comment: By the way, you do not need to cast it to `IEnumerable<Recording>`; a `List<T>` already implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so no conversion is needed, the way shown in the answer.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. But for some reason in my code Records.ItemsSource is showing up IEnumerable (Not IEnumerable<T>, just IEnumerable). I don't know why.

Comment: Where is that `Records` defined?

Comment: Records is a System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox. It is defined in the xaml as shown above. Controls is xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"

Answer (score -1):

Records.SelectedItem = Records.Items[0]; ?

Comment: -1 This does not filter the items, it simply returns the first one, which may not match the input.